# WCF Data Services ODATA throwing error with JSONP

Tags: json, jsonp, wcf-data-services, odata

Ok so I have a WCF ODATA service hosted locally for testing purposes. Then I have a Kendo Grid trying to query the service using a Kendo Datasource configured for ODATA exactly like the demo!

On the deployed service, I also implemented the "JSONPSupportBehavior" attribute and class that everyone is talking about!

Still I get this in Fiddler : A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the acceptable MIME types for the request. The supported type(s) 'application/atom+xml;type=feed, application/atom+xml, application/json;odata=verbose' do not match any of the acceptable MIME types 'application/json'

Is this IIS issue now or something else? This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change made in the WCF Data Services release. In order to get JSON response back (or JSONP) you need to send Accept header with value application/json;odata=verbose. Pure "application/json" is now reserved for the soon to be coming JSON Light format.
See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/11/what-happened-to-application-json-in-wcf-ds-5-0.aspx for more details.

Comment: I did the JSONSupportBehavior. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DataServicesJSONP Was that not supposed to take care of that?

Comment: Not really - that extension supports two things. The $format and the $callback. $callback is for JSONP. Anyway - look through its code and if you see application/json anywhere, just replace it with application/json;odata=verbose. That should fix it as well. The extension works by modifying the accept header if you use the $format, so you need to teach it the new accept header as well.